# Return Single Value From Subquery nested inside a case statment

Tags: sql, subquery, case

I have an archive table that stores information.  One of the values stored is an ID that I can relate back to a district name from another table.  The value of this ID can be 0 or greater than 0.  If the value is 0 it is unuseable, I just want it to display an empty string (NULL would be fine too), if the ID is greater than 0, I want to replace the ID with the District Name it relates to.  NOTE:  I cannot just relate the ID back directly to the Districts table because that returns multiple duplicate records (hence the Top (1)).

Is this actually possible, if not is there a another approach?

```
SELECT TeacherID, StartTime, EndTime,

   (Case TeacherScheduleArchice.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID

   When 0 THEN ''

   Else 

   SELECT Top(1) DistrictName From Districts Where District.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID =  TeacherScheduleArchice.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID

   END) As District

   FROM         TeacherScheduleArchive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need an additional set of parentheses:

```
SELECT TeacherID, StartTime, EndTime,
       (Case TeacherScheduleArchice.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID
            When 0 THEN ''
            Else (SELECT Top(1) DistrictName
                  From Districts
                  Where District.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID =  TeacherScheduleArchice.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID
                 )
       END) As District
FROM  TeacherScheduleArchive;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, you just have to put the parentheses around the subselect - and can leave them away around the `CASE`:

```
SELECT TeacherID, StartTime, EndTime,
   Case TeacherScheduleArchice.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID
   When 0 THEN ''
   Else 
   (SELECT Top(1) DistrictName
      From Districts
     Where District.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID = TeacherScheduleArchice.TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID
   )
   END As District
   FROM         TeacherScheduleArchive
```

However, I would use `DISTINCT` instead of `Top(1)` as that returns the single value if there is only one, just repeated several times. But it would cause an error in case there are distinct values for the same `TeacherStudent_ServiceTypeID`. This would warn you instead of returning an arbitrary entry.